# I get char error while trying to pars CSV file into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am practicing pandas and i have next issue:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position
>   7190: invalid start byte

So its simple tryout of csv readout:

```
csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r', encoding="UTF-8")
csv_pandas = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep=",")
print(csv_pandas)
```

However it works properly with csv module. With csv.reader i dont get same error.

Whats going on? And where can i learn more about charmap and encodings with python?

p.s. I tried out by removing encoding="UTF-8" and i got similar error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position
>   140378: character maps to

Comment: Have you tried `csv_pandas = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding='utf-8')` ?

Comment: Have you tried `csv_pandas = pd.read_csv(csvfile, dtype='str', encoding='ISO-8859-1')` ?

Comment: @Nand 

it works thank you very much.

Comment: @JonClements Yes it works thank you very much!

Comment: `latin` is easier than `ISO-8859-1`